# Is it possible to go through the content of ? in laravel query builder?

Tags: laravel

There is an array.
I put in where in Laravel query.

I would like to examine the contents of SQL.

```
$listArray = [1, 2, 3];
Stack::where('a_certain_column', $listArray)->toSql();
```

But the `toSql()` show:

> where (`a_certain_column` = ?)

I just wanted to check the Array put in <?> properly.

Comment: Have a look at the [query debugging](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#debugging) methods.

Answer (score 0):

is it whereIn ?

Stack::whereIn('a_certain_column',$listArray);
since its you search for array

Answer (score 0):

Please use this package it will give you the dynamic generated query result:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Steps :

1. `composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev`
2. add the ServiceProvider to the providers array in config/app.php

   Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
3. Add this under facades array in config/app.php

   'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facades\Debugbar::class,

Answer (score 0):

in your case it has to be whereIn Statment.
So the code will look like:

```php
$listArray = [1, 2, 3];
Stack::query()->whereIn('a_certain_column', $listArray)->toSql(); // or dd() instead of toSql()
```